# .innerHTML not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

Im working on a select box that populates based on another select box in an onChange event. It works great in every browser but IE.

```
function getVersion(str){
if (str==""){
    document.getElementById("vSelect").innerHTML="<option value=''>Please Select a product</option>";
return;
}

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("vSelect").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","includes/version.php?product="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

It changes this

```
<label>Version: </label>
<select id='vSelect'>
    <option value=''>Please Select a product</option>
</select>
```

in IE when the onchange fires it just clears out the text of the select. Any Ideas? I am trying to do this without loading a library.

Comment: Try not using `innerHTML`, as `innerHTML` is horrible. Instead, create an `<option>` element and add it: `var newOption = document.createOption('option'); newOption.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Please select a product')); document.getElementById('vSelect').appendChild(newOption);` It may not work (I can’t test it out), but it will not work better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a known bug in IE that microsoft confirmed "innerHTML" fails to work on the Select Object in IE and it is declared in this [page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228). they have given the workaround suggesting to wrap a div around the select tag and to use innerHTML. see the same page for the workaround. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, ill try looking into an implementation of that. I dont know who the dude is down voting everyone but this is great info to me.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change contents of a `<select>` in IE.  You'll have to replace the entire `<select>` element