# Javascript/JQuery to sort select element and account for label attribute in options

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text, label

I noticed the jquery options and examples only accounted for the text and value attributes and when I tried to simply add the label attribute I got errors.
I would like the sort to also include the label attribute where the select box does not have a specific id but a unique name (autogenerated).
An example with Javascript or Jquery would be fine for this (using the list below)

```html
<select multiple="true" style="width: 100px" size="6" name="staff_user_id_name[]">
<option label="dave matthews" value="1e7cfe4c-efc5-30fe-5135102574ac">dave matthews</option>
<option label="john adams" value="51803382-0a1e-44ec-511d461fd449">john adams</option>
<option label="justin timbers" value="471295fd-c3ae-9700-51487e79c590">justin timbers</option>
<option label="adam lion" value="a4dc7d17-36d0-8077-4f881e418250">adam lion</option>
<option label="june berstein" value="330bbd97-c025-e2e6-51fc14473736">june berstein</option>
</select>
```

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
// get the selected object by the beginning part of the name
var $sls = $('select[name^=staff_user_id_name]');

if ($sls.length > 0) { 
  var selectedVal = $sls.val();

  var $options = $('option', $sls);
  var arrVals = [];

  $options.each(function () {
    // push each option value and text into the array
    arrVals.push({
      val: $(this).val(),

      text: $(this).text(),

      });
  });
  arrVals.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.text.toLowerCase() > b.text.toLowerCase()) {
{
      return 1;
    } 
    else if (a.text == b.text) {
      return 0;
    } 
    else {
      return - 1;
    }
  });
  // loop through the sorted array and set the text/values to the options
  for (var i = 0, l = arrVals.length; i < l; i++) {
   $($options[i]).val(arrVals[i].val).text(arrVals[i].text);

  } 
  // set the selected value back
  $sls.val(selectedVal);
}


} ); // end jQuery
```

Comment: where's the code you said doesn't work? That's the whole point of this site, not just to have someone else write new code for you. People are here to help, not do work for others

Comment: Code added.
Did not realize it was not included in my earlier snippets.

Comment: what is the specific problem? I don't really understand the point of changing all the text for the options. If all you want is to sort there are simpler ways. You can sort the elements themselves

Comment: The form and included select box in generated from terse java code that would require significantly more access and effort to change. I expect to use jquery to simply change the order of the options select box without losing their value and label attributes.
So far I have been able to sort the text(innerText) and value attributes with jQuery but not the label (did not find jQuery selector to access this).

Comment: sort the elements themselves based on the label values or tex, far less code and simpler to read

Comment: I also noticed that the sort only worked in FF and Chrome but not in IE 8 or 9. 
The select element does not have a unique id only a name (unique for the form and page), that is why I do not target it by id.
I hope this helps to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sorting the array of elements themselves and replacing the inner html with the newly sorted options

```
$('select[name^="staff_user_id_name"]').html(function(){
    return $(this).children().sort(function(a,b){
       return $(a).text().toLowerCase() >  $(b).text().toLowerCase();
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n7szj7L6/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your response. While it works on jsfiddle; the sort functionality does not work in IE8 or 9 (did you get a chance to test on those?). The jQuery library I can currently use is v1.4.4. The jQuery innerHTML issue is actually a known bug in IE, but the suggestions I found were to wrap the whole select in a div and rebuild it dynamically. i'll find the link.

Comment: F12 in IE does not show me any errors, but the sort is not executed. It simply is not acted upon.
The IE known issue can be seen at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/276228

Comment: For BrowserMode: IE8 (in an IE9 Browser Developer Tools), it throws errors that seem to be related to running jsfiddle itself in IE. That I was having trouble with even the options and text sort in IE was important to begin with and I just realized that I did not highlight this earlier (my apologies).

Comment: I've never had problems using this in ie9

Comment: Anyone tested this [http://jsfiddle.net/t5qd03a9/] in IE.9?
It does not work here.
It works on Chrome and FF but not IE9 even with the oldest and latests jQuery versions (1.6.4 to 2.1.0 and everything in between).

You can't change contents of a <select> in IE. You'll have to replace the entire <select> element from (from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18434903/innerhtml-not-working-in-ie) is this accurate?